# Связанные данные ManyToManyField Django Python

Tags: python, django, orm

Мне надо чтобы в модели, была запись ManyToManyField по отношению к самой модели
То есть допустим есть

- продукт
- надо выборочно связать продукт с другими продуктами, которые уже есть в базе

правильная ли у меня логика, что я создаю в самой модели Products ForeignKey на модель ProductsRelated c ManyToManyField на Products? то есть какая-то рекурсия получается

**models.py**

```
 class Products(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')    
        related = models.ForeignKey('ProductsRelated', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    
    
    class ProductsRelated(models.Model):
        related = models.ManyToManyField(Products)
```

**в данном примере выдает ошибку (plugins это реальное имя моделей, в примере сверху переименовал для наглядности)**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crm3`.`#sql-1a98_3f`, CONSTRAINT `plugins_plugins_related_id_51d4783b_fk_plugin
s_pluginsrelated_id` FOREIGN KEY (`related_id`) REFERENCES `plugins_pluginsrelated` (`id`))')
```

Comment: related = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

Comment: а как исключить текущий продукт из возможной выборки? есть лайфхак?